# How do I specify a wav file on my sdcard as a Uri

Tags: android

I want to play a wav file on the sdcard using the MediaPlayer class. The Android developer's website says that we can play local media as a uri. The code snippet is

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

How do I set the local file as a Uri?
---EDIT---
Thanks to everyone for the answers
I ended up using `Uri myuri = Uri.parse(filepath)` but I have also verified that all the answers work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
File file = new File("myfile.wav");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: So it looks like I can change any string into Uri, and according to @Kunals answer below, the file can be loaded directly from it's path and we don't even need the Uri version. Then what is this Uri anyway, and why is this feature even there?

Comment: Yes you are right, the file can be loaded directly from its path. But an Uri is a more generic concept, is something that could identify an abstract or physical resource. For example your audio file could be located on a web server, rather than the sdcard.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
 String path = "/sdcard/music/sample music.mp3";
 mPlayer.setDataSource(path);
 mPlayer.prepare();
 mPlayer.start();    
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can I skip that setwakemode() thing? I am just learning Android so I want to keep the programs as basic as possible.

Comment: Please confirm if that solved your problem. If yes, please upvote the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Kunal: You should not use sdcard instead use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: @Arshad Parwez, I was just giving sample, but right, I should use proper API, Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1'ed. Incidentally, what is Uri and why do we even need it, if the MediaPlayer can directly read from the file path, and any string can as easily be converted into a Uri?

Comment: i am not sure, I am quite new too with android.

Answer (score 1):

The SD card directory may be system specific, so you need to query that first and then create a File and a Uri from it.

```
String sdcardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File sourdFile = new File(sdCardDirectory + "/path/to/soudfile/" + "sound.wav");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile();
```

Alternatively, you can build the Uri with `fromParts()`

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("file", "/" + sdCardDirectory + "/path/to/soudfile/" + "sound.wav", null);
```